# Make Function Wait Until First Function is Completed to Run

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this function in my React App.  It calls a few other functions.  Everything works except, I need the `.then(() => this.getHCAid())` to complete before `.then(() => this.addDocsList())` runs. I have not been able to make that happens. I'm sure it's simple, I just don't know how.

```
createHCA() {
      fetch(API_URL + `/hca/create`, {
        method: "PUT",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          client: this.state.client,
          short: this.state.short,
        }),
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      })
        .then((res) => {
          if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error();
          }
          return res.json();
        })
        .then((data) => console.log(data))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
        .then(() => this.getHCAid())      <--- Need this to complete
        .then(() => this.addDocsList())   <--- Before this runs
        .then(() => this.getAllHCAs());
        this.setState({ showHide: false});
  }
```

Comment: That's exactly what should be happening already.  What do these functions *do* and how are you observing the problem?

Comment: what exactly does `getHCAid` do? If it's asynchronous, you can make it return a promise. If it's synchronous, then just put the 2 calls together: `.then(() => { this.getHCAid(); this.addDocsList(); })`

Comment: Yes, it needs to be synchronous.  The first one(getHCAid) grabs the id of the last record created in a certain table.  Then (addDocsList) uses that id to create other records associated to it in another table.  What happens now it addDocsList runs too soon and uses the client Id previous to the one I need.

I guess to say it more simply, the first one returns a value and uses setState to that value.  The 2nd function needs to then use that this.state value.

Comment: You can't use a newly set `state` value in the same render cycle. If you need to use that value, you should make it available to the next `.then` directly, not rely on retrieving it from state. Also, your final `setState({showHide})` will run before the `.then` chain is finished.

Answer (score 0):

I'd encourage you to do a couple of things here...

- Use async/await rather than a myraid of `.then` promises memoize
  these function calls and use a `useEffect` (or multiple) with
  dependencies to control when side-effects should be triggered. Convert to functional component to achieve this result.
- "showHide" is a very confusing term for future developers, be kind to
  your future self and future devs and make a term like "show" or
  "isHidden"
- If you really want to continue this pattern (chained .then statements), put your `.catch` at the very bottom to handle any issues/errors. This is where async/await is worth the time to quickly learn.
- You only want functions doing one main thing, and this is to createHCA, let your other code trigger the functions. As you scale you will be thankful you did.

```
async function createHCA() {
  let data
      try {
        data = await fetch(API_URL + `/hca/create`, {
            method: "PUT",
            body: JSON.stringify({
              client: this.state.client,
              short: this.state.short,
            }),
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          })
      } catch e => {
        throw new Error(e.message)
        return 
      } 
         this.setState({ showHide: false});
         return data?.json()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there are two issues going on here.

The first is that your functions sound like database queries or updates which will be asynchronous so you can't rely on the next step in the cycle to have access to any data returned if it hasn't been told to wait.

The solution you tried to come up with, setting state in one of the `then` methods, won't work either because it too batches up queries and processes them asynchronously, and the next step won't have access to that data either.

So, ideally what you should probably do is use [a promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to return the id from `getHCAid`, and then pass that into `addDocsList` which also returns a promise, etc.

Here's a simplified example using [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await).

```
getHCAid() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    // Do DB process, get an id
    res(id);
  });
}

async getData() {
  const response = await fetch(API_URL);
  const data = await response.json();
  const id = await this.getHCAid();
  const list = await this.addDocsList(id);
  const hcas = await this.getAllHCAs();
  this.setState({ showHide: false });
}
```